# R how to filter for, remove and/or edit incorrect observations

Tags: r, filter, time-series

I am attempting to do some quality control on my coral demography database.  Here I have provided a dummy dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(`Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PR", "PR", 
"PC", "PR", "PC", "PR", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), ID = c("W1", 
"W1", "W1", "W1", "W2", "W2", "W2", "W2", "W3", "W3", "W3", "W3", 
"W4", "W4", "W4", "W4", "W5", "W5", "W5", "W5", "W6", "W6", "W6", 
"W6"), Date = c("1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20", "1/2/17", 
"1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20", "1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20", 
"1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20", "1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", 
"1/2/20", "1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20"), Year = c(17, 
18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20), Site_long = c("Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
"Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki"), Shelter = c("High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High"), `Module #` = c(115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115), Side = c("N", 
"N", "N", "N", "S", "S", "S", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), Location = c("A2", 
"A2", "A2", "A2", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", 
"D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2"), Settlement_Area = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75), TimeStep = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4), size_class = c(1, 1, 2, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), `Cover Code` = c(1, 1, 2, NA, 
1, NA, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    `Max Diameter (mm)` = c(6, 9, 12, NA, 3, NA, 8, NA, 8, 8, 
    10, 13, 2, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 9, 14, 8, 12, 16, 18), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Height (mm)` = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Status Code` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    "NF", NA, "NF", NA, "D", NA, "D", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X18 = c("coral with NF at end, no change needed", 
    NA, NA, NA, "coral with NF in middle (refound), need to delete TimeStep 2 measurement with NF", 
    NA, NA, NA, "coral thought to be dead but actually survived, need to switch \"D\" to \"ND\"", 
    NA, NA, NA, "coral that was misidentified and needs to be changed to PR", 
    NA, NA, NA, "coral that was misidentified but thought it was actually PC like originally identified when it was found to actually be PR in the 4th TimeStep, need all entries to be the most recent taxonomic group identified for this coral", 
    NA, NA, NA, "coral which was properly identified originally and survived to the last TimeStep", 
    NA, NA, NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -24L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    `Taxonomic Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Site_long = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Shelter = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Module #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Side = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Location = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Settlement_Area = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), TimeStep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), size_class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Cover Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Diameter (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), `Height (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), `Status Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X18 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I want to find corals within my database that were marked as being either not found (Status Code = NF) or dead (Status Code = D) and were found in a following TimeStep.  For example:

W2: This coral was not found (NF) during TimeStep 2 but it was found in the next quarter.  This means that the coral didn't actually die.  As such, I want to remove this row (observation) only such that W2 coral will have observations only for TimeSteps 1, 3, and 4.

W3: This coral was thought to have died during TimeStep 2 but was found to be alive in TimeStep 3.  Because it was found alive in TimeStep 3, I want the "Status Code" for TimeStep 2 to be changed to "ND" instead of "D".  So unlike with "NF" entries, I don't want the row to be deleted but instead replaced with "ND".

#### Desired Database

```
data_desired <- structure(list(`Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC"), ID = c("W1", "W1", 
"W1", "W1", "W2", "W2", "W2", "W3", "W3", "W3", "W3", "W4", "W4", 
"W4", "W4", "W5", "W5", "W5", "W5", "W6", "W6", "W6", "W6"), 
    Date = c("1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20", "1/2/17", 
    "1/2/19", "1/2/20", "1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20", 
    "1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20", "1/2/17", "1/2/18", 
    "1/2/19", "1/2/20", "1/2/17", "1/2/18", "1/2/19", "1/2/20"
    ), Year = c(17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 
    18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20), Site_long = c("Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki"), Shelter = c("High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
    "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High"), `Module #` = c(115, 
    115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
    115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115), Side = c("N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "S", "S", "S", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "S", 
    "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), Location = c("A2", 
    "A2", "A2", "A2", "B3", "B3", "B3", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", 
    "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D2", "D2", 
    "D2", "D2"), Settlement_Area = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
    0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 
    0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75), TimeStep = c(1, 
    2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
    2, 3, 4), size_class = c(1, 1, 2, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), `Cover Code` = c(1, 
    1, 2, NA, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), `Max Diameter (mm)` = c(6, 9, 12, NA, 3, 8, NA, 
    8, 8, 10, 13, 2, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 9, 14, 8, 12, 16, 18), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Height (mm)` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Status Code` = c(NA, NA, NA, "NF", 
    NA, NA, "D", NA, "ND", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -23L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(`Taxonomic Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Site_long = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Shelter = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Module #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Side = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Location = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Settlement_Area = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), TimeStep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), size_class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Cover Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Diameter (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), `Height (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), `Status Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

At the end of the day, I am looking for all code to be general such that this can be applied to my full database.  Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: what have you tried so far ... ??

Comment: Please try to remove space in your column names. ``Status_Code`` is much easier to work with than ``Status Code``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

result <- data %>% 
  arrange(ID, Date, .bygroup = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(found = rev(cumsum(is.na(rev(`Status Code`))) > 0),
         `Status Code` = ifelse(found & `Status Code` == "NF", "X", `Status Code`),
         `Status Code` = ifelse(found & `Status Code` == "D", "ND", `Status Code`)) %>%
  filter(`Status Code` != "X" | is.na(`Status Code`))
```

It's quite difficult to show that this is right because of the width of your tibble, so here I have selected only the necessary columns and converted to a data frame to show this is the correct result:

```r
as.data.frame(select(result, ID, Date, `Status Code`, `Site_long`))
#>    ID   Date Status Code Site_long
#> 1  W1 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 2  W1 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 3  W1 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 4  W1 1/2/20          NF   Waikiki
#> 5  W2 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 6  W2 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 7  W2 1/2/20           D   Waikiki
#> 8  W3 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 9  W3 1/2/18          ND   Waikiki
#> 10 W3 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 11 W3 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 12 W4 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 13 W4 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 14 W4 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 15 W4 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 16 W5 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 17 W5 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 18 W5 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 19 W5 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 20 W6 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 21 W6 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 22 W6 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
#> 23 W6 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
```

Answer (score 1):

**Version 1 Based on Original Request**

Here is a solution using `lead` from `dplyr` and not grouping by `ID`.

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  filter((is.na(`Status Code`) | (`Status Code` != "NF") ) | ((`Status Code` == "NF") & ID != lead(ID))) %>% 
  mutate(`Status Code`= ifelse(
    (`Status Code` == "D" & is.na(lead((`Status Code`))) & ID == lead(ID)),
    "ND",`Status Code`))
```

Seems to give the same result based on showing same data frame as in answer by @Allan Cameron

```
> as.data.frame(select(data2, ID, Date, `Status Code`, `Site_long`))
   ID   Date Status Code Site_long
1  W1 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
2  W1 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
3  W1 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
4  W1 1/2/20          NF   Waikiki
5  W2 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
6  W2 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
7  W2 1/2/20           D   Waikiki
8  W3 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
9  W3 1/2/18          ND   Waikiki
10 W3 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
11 W3 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
12 W4 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
13 W4 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
14 W4 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
15 W4 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
16 W5 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
17 W5 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
18 W5 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
19 W5 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
20 W6 1/2/17        <NA>   Waikiki
21 W6 1/2/18        <NA>   Waikiki
22 W6 1/2/19        <NA>   Waikiki
23 W6 1/2/20        <NA>   Waikiki
```

---

**Version 2 based on Updated Request in Comments**

I think the below will do what you are requesting i.e.  change to be made from "D" to "ND" if there are any observations after the "TimeStep" in question. It does not matter what the Status Code is".

If you want to include some updated data that can be tested, that would help debug if it doesn't behave as needed.

I just removed `` & is.na(lead((`Status Code`))) `` in the `mutate` line of code.  So if the "Status Code" is anything other than "D" in the next observation for that "ID" it should recode "D" to "ND".

```
data3 <- data %>% 
  filter((is.na(`Status Code`) | (`Status Code` != "NF") ) | ((`Status Code` == "NF") & ID != lead(ID))) %>% 
  mutate(`Status Code`= ifelse(
    (`Status Code` == "D" & ID == lead(ID)), "ND",`Status Code`))
```

Comment: Russ Thomas thank you for your response!  Do you happen to know if you can alter your code so `Status Code` following the misidentified dead coral (measurment occured in a TimeStep after the observation with `Status Code` = "D") does not have to be NA?  I ask because ```[r] !is.na(`Status Code`) ``` is possible in my database

Comment: Hi @Eric Dilley.  so in the TimeStep immediately after ```Status code``` = "D",  ```Status Code``` could be something other than "NA", right?  What would the other possible values be, and would "D" still need to be changed to "ND" or something else?

Comment: it could be a variety of things.  That's why if it is possible I want to make the code general so that the value of `Status Code` is either a.) NA, b.) NF, c.) D, or d.) another character value.  So in short I want the change to be made from "D" to "ND" if there are any observations after the TimeStep in question.  It does not matter what the `Status Code` is.

Comment: Hi @EricDilley, I had an error in the first updated version I posted a few minutes ago. I just updated and reposted so please use the updated Version 2 above if you used the code I posted prior to adding this comment. Apologies for the extra confusion.